# How to block user group in Linux?

Tags: linux, debian

I can block one user by command `sudo usermod --lock user_name` and unblock it by `sudo usermod --unlock user_name`.

There is a way to block whole user group? (I use Debian 7.2).

I looked `groupmod --help`. There is no words about block.

Comment: well blocking the group is not advisable as there might be multiple users belonging to the group, if you want to block entire group you can put # in /etc/groups in front of the group name so it won't be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`groupmod` is about modifying properties of the group itself, and being locked is a property of users, not groups.

But you can loop over members of a group and lock them:

```
for user in $(grep ^$group: /etc/group | sed -e s/.*:// -e 's/,/ /g'); do
    sudo usermod --lock $i
done
```

The same thing without `grep`:

```
for user in $(sed -ne "/^$group:/{s/.*://; s/,/ /gp}" /etc/group); do
    sudo usermod --lock $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try lgroupmod -L, http://linux.die.net/man/1/lgroupmod

Or passwd -l,  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-locking-an-account/